# Can we have the tag game-controller?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Can we have the tag [game-controller](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/game-controller) with [joystick](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/joystick) and [gamepad](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/gamepad) as synonyms?

Excerpt:

> Questions related to using game controllers like gamepads and joysticks with Ubuntu.

I tried looking around on [gaming.stackexchange.com](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/controllers/info), U&L and [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/tags/game-controller/info), but there isn't much more than organizing that can be done currently. The joystick tag has no wiki page on U&L and SU ([1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/joystick), [2](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/joystick)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But which one is the master tag?

- Both "joystick" and "gamepad" describe the hardware format.
- The systems in Ubuntu as a type of joystick (`/dev/input/jsn` devices, `jstest`, `jscal`, etc). Older users will probably preference "joystick". Console users will probably preference "controller".
- Nobody has seen fit to tag something as a game-controller to date. It's not a natural expression.
- Hardcore sim users wouldn't call a joystick a *game* controller.

We can discount the last group but I still don't know whether we use Ubuntu's classic convention or what is most commonly used. Is picking *something else* ("game-controller") better than something that's already used?

Opinions?

Comment: Sorry if I got it backwards, I meant that *game-controller* should be the master tag for almost all input devices primarily used for gaming/simulation. While my dualshock 4 and my arcade fightstick are detected as `/dev/input/jsN` I wouldn't *prefer* to tag questions about these as joystick, even if the latter almost qualifies as such (users in forums of fighter games might disagree and want to differentiate). *Controller* seems to be neutral, adding *gaming* to it avoids confusion with something else and is actually used on SU, where joystick is almost ignored.

Comment: No, that's my fault for not mentioning it. I've edited. I'm not against it but adding a new tag to replace what has already organically been used suggests we're probably being overly politically correct. Just going with the numbers (with "gamepad")  might make more sense than munging the terms we actually use into something nobody uses organically.

Comment: Just a thought - when people start getting steam-boxes we might have more gamepad/game-controller questions.